# Java + SSH + Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, ssh

We are implementing an university project: a car-pooling service in Java.

We need to solve a problem linked "how to manage a postgres server":
the PostgreSQL Database is configured in a lab server called "golem" (130.136.4.sth) reachable only through terminals in the same subnet (130.136.4.0).
We have four account (ours) through we can establish a ssh connection to an host.

Is it possible to make SQL queries through SSH towards Postgres DB in JAVA?

Thank you :)
Davide

Comment: Take a look at this. It's not the complete answer but i think it is a part of it, at least the SSH connection: http://www.example-code.com/java/ssh_exec.asp

Comment: What have you tried?....seriously...I'm tied of reading open ended questions...

Comment: @Brendan: Sorry but we haven't tried anything yet because we aren't java experts. So We were looking for hints from you experts :) Maybe a design pattern verified instead of bad solutions found otherwere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is just for development, you can use ssh port forwarding to access the database as if it was installed locally. How port forwarding is enabled depends on the client software you use, openssh for example has a command line switch for it (-L):

```
ssh user@host -L localport:remotehost:remoteport
```

This command would make the `remoteport` on `remotehost`, though accessible only through `host`, available on `localport` on your computer.

Comment: You can also tell ssh to listen on 0.0.0.0:localport instead of the default 127.0.0.1:localport by passing the `-g` option (see man page). You should NOT do this unless you really need it, but if you need it it's there. This exposes "remotehost:remoteport" via "<yourhost>:localport" to *EVERYONE* who can contact "<yourhost>:yourport" so make sure that "remotehost:remoteport" has strong security set up and/or use iptables on the forwarding host to limit access to the port.

Comment: There's no real reason to use that approach just for development, either. Adding an option for your Java app to spawn an SSH session to tunnel traffic over is easy. ssh port forwards are very solid, though performance under congestion can be iffy [because tunneling TCP within TCP  confuses TCP's congestion control and rate algorithms(http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html). If you don't want to spawn a process, [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) supports port forwarding and IP tunnelling via native Java ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the other suggested answers as they seem easier to accomplish what you need.

However, if you really need to implement the command submission with Java for your lab assignment, you can take a look at the JSch (Java Secure Channel) library found here: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ Examples are here http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/

With it you can submit ssh commands and perform any kind of operation via a Java API

Comment: Handily, it looks like JSch can also tunnel IP, so they can even access Pg via the SSH session if direct access is firewalled off or filtered.

Comment: We're trying this solution.

Hint: Manually solution works:
ssh user_lab@lucia.cs.unibo.it //
>enter password user_lab //
psql -h golem -U ingsw12_03 ingsw12_03 //
ingsw12_03=> (Access postresql server ok) //

This is java "solution":
http://pastebin.com/QrM2UkHD

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.

Changing String rhost="golem"
and
urlAlfresco = "jdbc:postgresql://golem:"+rport+"/ingsw12_03";

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection failed 
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: golem

How to solve? :(

Comment: ...@DavideAguiari I wouldn't publicly expose your username, host and IP address.

Comment: Don't worry. Users are fake and IP is high firewalled by University.

Answer (score 1):

If you run "ssh" followed by any command that command gets executed on the remote host.  So you should be able to run pre-baked queries in batch mode via ssh.

Consider doing key-gen and key exchanges to enable passwordless ssh execution.

Example (this just dumps a directory listing to your terminal):

```
ssh me@mybox ls
```